# How could I differentiate between static methods and instance methods in javascript declaration typescript files from definitelyTyped?

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

How do I recognise static methods and instance methods and the others from the javascript declaration typescript files from [definitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)? 
Say, exampleString.length is an instance method, whereas, 
 String.fromCharCode() is a static method. 
 
I was looking for a way to write a script that would recognise the static methods from the other. say something using typescript services api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too long for a comment.**

Firstly, `String.prototype.length` is not a method, it is a value. If constructor function is defined using `class` keyword, you can detect static and non-static method by checking whether a method is defined in constructor or in instance.

```
class foo{
  bar(){}
  static baz(){}
}

var instance = new foo();

console.log(instance.constructor.bar); // undefined
console.log(instance.constructor.baz); // [Function: baz]
console.log(instance.bar); // [Function: bar]
console.log(instance.baz); // undefined
```

So, you can conclude that `baz` is static and `bar` is non-static method. Also, `String.length` is a bad example: `someString.length` has reference to `String.prototype.length`, but `String.length` has reference to `Function.prototype.length`.

Comment: oh, sorry about .length, but I was looking for a way to write a script that would recognise the static methods from the other. say something using typescript services api.